# Can a planet's magnetic field be generated by non-ferromagnetic metals?

Tags: geology

I am trying to construct a terrestrial planet that is almost entirely made of silicates but with a core that's able to generate a magnetic field. I really don't want to use iron, nickel, or cobalt, and was wondering if I could use a non-ferromagnetic metal. I was thinking maybe titanium (aparently its weakly magnetic). Would this be possible? Or would the magnetic field be too weak? I know that Jupiter has a field from metallic hydrogen so I don't know what is and isnt possible at this point.

Comment: I don't think it’s possible. If you have particular aversions to iron, nickel and cobalt, how about gadolinium or dysprosium? Both are ferromagnetic.

Comment: Iron is not ferromagnetic in the conditions prevalent at the Earth's core, so the answer is trivial: yes, it is possible, because we have the example of Earth, which has a magnetic field and its magnetic field is not generated by ferromagnetic materials. (Hint: the [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) of iron is about 800 degrees Celsius.)

Comment: Where in that star system did the heavier elements go?

Answer (score 17):

Yes. The fact that the Earth's core is made of materials that are ferromagnetic at standard temperature and pressure is completely coincidental--it has no bearing on the generation of the geomagnetic field. In the regions where the field is generated, iron and nickel are in fact *not* ferromagnetic.

All that's necessary is that you have an electrically conductive fluid. Experimental simulations of the geodynamo make use of rotating spheres of molten sodium. Molten titanium should work just fine.

Comment: Diamagnetic elements are slightly repelled by a magnetic field and paramagnetic elements are slightly attracted by a magnetic field. Hydrogen (including metallic hydrogen) is diamagnetic. Titanium is paramagnetic and so is sodium. https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/MagParticle/Physics/MagneticMatls.htm and https://periodictable.com/Properties/A/MagneticType.html

Comment: @mchid So, since sodium works in experimental models, it would seem that the diamagnetic vs. paramegnetic properties of the metal are in fact also irrelevant, and molten titanium should work!

Comment: Yes titanium should work because paramagnetic electrons are [only aligned when in the presence of a magnetic field](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Graphical-illustration-of-ferromagnetic-ferrimagnetic-paramagnetic-and-diamagnetic_fig3_254705371) sort of like iron is in a molten state.

Answer (score 10):

**To generate a planetary magnetic field you just need a liquid metal where electrons can float freely.**

There are several options for this, these are a few examples which come to mind:

- Iron and Nickel

This is the Earth setup, but I thought I'd mention it. [Wikipedia explains pretty well how it is generated.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field)

- Metallic Hydrogen

This is the [Jovian setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Jupiter) and shows that one doesn't even need a true metal.

- Magnesium Oxide

[Some recent reasearch](https://carnegiescience.edu/news/magnesium-oxide-earth-super-earth) suggests that magnesium oxide turns into a conductive liquid at pressures one might expect in super-earths. This is the most realistic bet in my opinion.